# allow users to skip questions

Tags: crowdflower

I'm trying to annotate a dataset using crowdflower where the users might not be sure about the answer in some instances. Is there a way to allow users to "skip" questions, or replace one question by another?

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** use the `required` validator and the contributor will be able to send his judgment **without** providing an answer for any of your fields.

I'm not sure there is a way to replace a question by another, though.

Comment: I am working on the same thing. So if the field is not required will they be payed for the job if they submit the empty form?